# JFET series switch

Tags: jfet

[image]

The picture shows a series JFET switch. Is r_d itself the load or does the load have to be attached at the port v_out? If the second one is true then what is the purpose of r_d? Can't  we replace r_d with the load we want?

Comment: There are three connection points plus earth in the left diagram and I'm unsure what the right diagram is meant to represent.

Comment: @Andyaka i'm sorry, let me edit the picture.

Comment: @Andyaka it is edited now, these two figure shows equivalent circuits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *my question is whether r_d itself is the load or the load has to be
> attached at the port v_out?*

The only sensible option (without further context) is that \$R_D\$ is an attached load. It certainly cannot be part of the JFET because it makes no connection to ground. The Vout circle symbol is a little confusing but, I believe, it's just showing the point where you measure Vout.

\$R_{DS}\$ is typically the drain-source on-resistance of the JFET.